# Renaming domain controller during migration

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller, migration, windows-server-2019

We're looking at replacing an aged server for a client, and as we installed this server, it adheres to our naming convention (namely, `SVR-DC` as it's the only DC on the network).

Now that we want to migrate to a new server (both new hardware as well as a fresh OS), is it feasible/recommended to rename both DCs at migration time? Ideally:

- Set up new DC as secondary with some name such as SVR-DC2
- At cutover, rename old DC to SVR-DC1
- Rename new DC to SVR-DC
- Depromo old DC, remove from domain, decommission
- Patch GPOs, application configs, etc, as necessary

Or optionally, leave the old DC (it's running 2012 r2) as secondary, however it's a well used install that would need some cleanup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having 2 DCs in your domain is a much healthier way to operate than having only one.

I've successfully renamed a DC with no issues, as long as you're not *recycling* the name of a previous DC (and haven't cleaned DNS/Sites and Services in the interim). And you have another DC with all the FSMO roles on it already.

Ensure the network adapter on the legacy DC is pointing to the new PDCe as its primary DNS. Rename it and reboot when prompted. When the DC comes up again after the rename and starts Netlogon, it should register its new SRV records.

After reboot and all the services have started, ensure the SRV records for the new name are registered in every appropriate place in the _msdcs zone in DNS. Ensure replication and DCDIAG are happy. Ensure the DC is showing up in the correct places in AD Sites and Services. Next day, if all is well, go into the _msdcs zone and clean up any records pointing to the legacy name.

**Alternatively**, if you want to clean up the server build - I'd simply upgrade it to 2019 now:

1. Demote the legacy DC first. After it reboots and all services have started, ensure the computer account is no longer in the Domain Controllers OU.
2. Remove it from the domain - join it to a workgroup.
3. Reimage the machine or whatever you're doing to rebuild it with the new name and join it to the domain.
4. Ensure the old computer account has gone. Check AD Sites and Services and the _msdcs zone in DNS and ensure there are no references to the old DC there.
5. DCPromo the "new" DC and go from there.

By the way, referring to "primary" and "secondary" DCs in AD is not appropriate. It's best to refer to the PDCe, if you must - primary/secondary is an NT thing, and the PDCe role can be on any DC.

Comment: So much good information here. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

1. Doing this isn't worth the potential headache. I've been through this operation when it didn't work correctly and in the end wished I hadn't undertaken it.
2. Is the name really so important? This seems a bit like tilting at windmills to me.
3. You should have at least two domain controllers, whether that's one old one and one new one or two new ones. I wouldn't leave a client with only one DC.

Comment: I agree, but my OCD wouldn't leave me alone. I would like the names to be similar, and after discussing with a more senior tech, I think we'll flip things around, name the new DC SVR-DC1, migrate over, set this as primary, and rename the old as SVR-DC2 and leave it as secondary controller.

With this in mind, the domain itself isn't in danger, my OCD is happy, and naming convention is happy as well.

Comment: Don't rename a DC.  The potential complications are not worth it.  If you want naming consistency, just spin up a second new server and scrap the old SRV-DC